# What's wrong with my memcpy?

Tags: c++

I have written a function to implement memcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
char *memcpy(char *dest,char *src,int n){

    char *ch=dest;
    while (n--)
        *ch++=*src++;
    return  dest;
}

int main(){

    char *src="georgia";
    int n=strlen(src);
    char *dest=new char[n];
    std::cout<<*memcpy(dest,src,n)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But it only prints a single `g`.  Why?

Comment: No need to copy `dest` into `ch`, just use it in the same manner you're using `n`. Strings in C++ should be pointed at by a `const char*`, so: `const char *src="georgia";`. The length of a string cannot be negative, and as such the result of `strlen` is an unsigned type, namely `size_t`. So don't use `int n` but `size_t n`. (This also applies to the number of bytes to copy; negative is meaningless, use a signed type.) Never do manual allocation! You're leaking `dest`; use a `std::vector` in place of dynamic arrays, so you can never leak. In the future, take out extraneous whitespace. :)

Comment: @GMan:  If the OP wants to return `dest`, he can't modify it (hence the need for `ch`).  Other than that I agree 100%.

Comment: @James: Well derp on me. Do keep `ch`. :)

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::copy()`?

Comment: @sbi: Or `std::string` for that matter. It's just a learning exercise, I suspect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you're printing a single character.

```
std::cout<<*memcpy(dest,src,n)<<std::endl;
```

This dereferences the destination buffer (`*memcpy`) and therefore returns the first character of the string (which is `g`). You should be fine using this:

```
std::cout << memcpy(dest, src, n) << std::endl;
```

Other than that, it's still not gonna work: you need to include the terminating NULL character of your string in the copy, but `strlen` excludes it from the length of the string; so your buffer is missing 1 character. You need to add 1 to `n` to balance it, and everything should be fine.

```
int n = strlen(src) + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with the memcpy function but you have the * operation on the result.  If we break the print line down it is...

```
char * result = memcpy(dest,src,n);
std::cout << *result << std::endl;
```

You really want...

```
std::cout << memcpy(dest,src,n) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `memcpy()` returns a pointer to `char`. In the line

```
std::cout<<*memcpy(dest,src,n)<<std::endl;
```

you dereference the pointer (you use operator*) so effectively you send one `char` (the one the return value points to) to the stream.

There is a bug in your code. `strlen` returns number of characters in the literal "georgia", but wihtout the terminating null character. You should increase `n` by one, to allocate appropriate storage for `dest` and to copy also the terminating null character.

Answer (score 2):

You're dereferencing a char*, which is a char. This will be the first character, g.